# Where can I find spanish documentation for creating LaTeX classes?

Tags: documentation, documentclass-writing, spanish

Searching the web for spanish documentation about creating classes for LaTeX, I found this [website](http://metodos.fam.cie.uva.es/~latex/apuntes/apuntes.html) belongs to the class of "Scientific text processing in high quality" (Procesamiento de textos científicos en alta calidad) at the University of Valladolid, Spain. Specifically the PDF file [apuntes8.pdf](http://metodos.fam.cie.uva.es/~latex/apuntes/apuntes8.pdf) contains information about LaTeX programming techniques. Also, the other documents contains very good information about basic and advanced use of LaTeX for text processing.

I thought that is a good idea post this information here. :)

If you know another source of spanish information for creating LaTeX classes feel free to share!.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [Javier Bezos site](http://www.tex-tipografia.com/) (I'm not speaking spanish so this is a guess really).

Comment: Thanx, but actually there is almost nothing on how to create classes. But if you have found it useful, I don't mind :-).